# Set Nomenclature in overleaf

Tags: nomenclature, overleaf

I have been trying to set a nomenclature for my thesis. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

In for example chapter 7 I added some \nomenclature{}{}. However, when I compile the file the nomenclature list remained empty.

Comment: Hi Iris, I'm a support staff at Overleaf. If your have a specific issue with your Overleaf project, you can email support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, and we can have a look at your project to see what's the issue.

Comment: Leaving a comment here in case this helps other users in future: On Overleaf, for packages like nomencl, glossaries to be processed correctly, the main .tex file to be compiled needs to be in the project's top level i.e. not in a folder.